# Не могу передать объект в лямбда-выражение. Ошибка: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, массивы, javafx, лямбда-выражение

Имеется цикличное создание и отображение кнопок. Каждая кнопка,по нажатию, должна передавать в функцию саму себя.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 17; j++) {
        Cell[i][j] = createButton((ArenaLine.getMaxWidth() / 20) * 1, (ArenaLine.getMaxHeight() / 9) * 1, (ArenaLine.getMaxWidth() / 20) * (j + 1), (ArenaLine.getMaxHeight() / 9) * (i + 1));
        ArenaLine.getChildren().add(Cell[i][j]);
        Cell[i][j].setOnAction((ActionEvent actionEvent) -> {
            Spawn(Cell[i][j]);
        });
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том,что `i` и `j` — локальные переменные, и функция выдает следующую ошибку на строке `Spawn(Cell[i][j]);`:

> error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final Spawn(Cell[i][j]);

Загвоздка в том, что я не могу передать конкретную ссылку на конкретную кнопку из-за изменчивости `i` и `j`.
Конечно, можно прописать для каждого элемента действие отдельно,но элементов в массиве крайне много.
Какие есть выходы из данной ситуации? Что можно тут придумать?

Comment: Как ругается, что говорит?

Comment: «разумеется» — самое опасное слово в разработке ПО. Распишите подробно, что происходит и что должно происходить. Приведите весь код, необходимый для понимания вопроса: сейчас можно только догадываться где объявлены классы и какая сигнатура у `Spawn`

Comment: Суть проблемы: 
Имеется цикличное создание и отображение кнопок. Каждая кнопка,по нажатию,должна передавать в функцию саму себя. Проблема заключается в том,что i и j - локальные переменные,и функция выдает следующую ошибку:"error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final Spawn(Cell[i][j]);"
Загвоздка в том,что я не могу передать конкретную ссылку на конкретную кнопку из-за изменчивости i и j.

Comment: @TrueASL Возможно стоит перенести последний ваш комментарий в тело вопроса с помощью кнопки __править__.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Довольно топорно, но:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 17; j++) {
        Cell[i][j] = createButton((ArenaLine.getMaxWidth() / 20) * 1, (ArenaLine.getMaxHeight() / 9) * 1, (ArenaLine.getMaxWidth() / 20) * (j + 1), (ArenaLine.getMaxHeight() / 9) * (i + 1));
        ArenaLine.getChildren().add(Cell[i][j]);
        final int ii = i;
        final int jj = j;
        Cell[ii][jj].setOnAction((ActionEvent actionEvent) -> {
            Spawn(Cell[ii][jj]);
        });
    }
}
```

или

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 17; j++) {
        final Button button = createButton((ArenaLine.getMaxWidth() / 20) * 1, (ArenaLine.getMaxHeight() / 9) * 1, (ArenaLine.getMaxWidth() / 20) * (j + 1), (ArenaLine.getMaxHeight() / 9) * (i + 1));
        Cell[i][j] = button; 
        ArenaLine.getChildren().add(button);
        button.setOnAction( ae -> {
            Spawn(button);
        });
    }
}
```

P.S. Не пишите имена переменных и методов с заглавной буквы, так не принято в `java`.

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор вам сказал, что нельзя использовать не финальные переменные в лямбдах. Так, что либо не используйте примитивы, либо не используйте лямбду(сделайте анонимным классом)